# Loss of Vim keybindings after screen detach and SSH logout

Tags: vim, ssh, key-bindings, freeze, gnu-screen

On one of the servers I commonly work with (Ubuntu 11.04), I get a hanging logout whenever I do following:

1. Log in via SSH
2. Start screen
3. Run Vim
4. {edit files, etc}
5. Detach screen session
6. Log out of server ("exit")

After doing, it hangs. (says "logout", never seems to actually log out). Furthermore, the next time I log in and reattach my screen session, it seems that all of my key bindings are gone in Vim. This includes the entire functionality of some plugins, like NERDTree.

I tried a few different combinations of these actions. For example, if I exit Vim before detaching my screen, it doesn't do this. It also doesn't do this if I don't run Vim at all, or if I don't run screen at all.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue is. I had my SSH client configured to forward X for that server. Disabling that fixed the problem. I don't really understand the details of why, but that's what it is.